# Why getUnchecked of Futures of guava is needed

Tags: java, guava

According to [Futures](https://guava.dev/releases/20.0/api/docs/com/google/common/util/concurrent/Futures.html#getChecked-java.util.concurrent.Future-java.lang.Class-) explanation for `getUnchecked`, the goal is to eliminate the `UncheckException`, I don't quite understand what is the benefit for this, what is the use case for API, more precisely speaking, in what situation, I need `getChecked` or getUnchecked` respectively? Thanks

Comment: Do you want to have to write `catch ExecutionException` _every time_ you call `Future.get()`, whether or not it's possible for an exception to occur?

Comment: Because normally a get may block until a result is given and you get the exception say if it times out.  If you want to see if there's a value I'll do something, but continue even if there isn't you'd use this.

Comment: You get a _different_ exception if you time out.  But not _all_ futures can fail at all.